# How to delay jquery mobile loader for 2 seconds?

Tags: jquery

How can I delay the loading indicator if an ajax call takes less then 2 seconds?

Loading indicator:

```
  $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"e", text:"Bitte warten...", textonly:false, textVisible: false});
```

Setting a timeout will result in showing the loading indicator after 2 seconds regardless of ajax call:

```
function load_filter(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"e", text:"Bitte warten  ...", textonly:false, textVisible: false});
},2000);
$.ajax({
  ...
```

How to delay, so the indicator does not popup for such a short amount of time?

Comment: You really want to do this? Ideally loader is only shown to user for some processing is going on. So if it's taking less time, it's actually good for user.

Comment: Yes, because the loader shows up for 0.x seconds and this is useless as it is distracting. I want a loader only if the user is wondering what is happening.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Following code might solve problem. Let me know if you have any queries. If you want delay success/delay processing, you can move that processing as well in setTimeout callback function.

```
    function hideLoader(timeBeforeAjax) {
        let timeafterAjax = new Date();
        let difference = timeafterAjax - timeBeforeAjax
        // difference is less 2000 set time out for 2000-difference 
        if (difference < 2000) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.mobile.loading('hide', {
                    theme: "e", text: "Bitte warten  ...", textonly: false,
                    textVisible: false
                });
            }, (2000 - difference));
        } else {
            // if time taken is greater than 2 second hide 
            $.mobile.loading('hide', {
                theme: "e", text: "Bitte warten  ...", textonly: false,
                textVisible: false
            });
        }

    };
    //start timer 
    let timeBeforeAjax = new Date();
    //show loader 
    $.mobile.loading('show', {
        theme: "e", text: "Bitte warten  ...", textonly: false,
        textVisible: false
    });
    //make ajax call
    $.ajax({
        success: function (data) {
            hideLoader(timeBeforeAjax);
            // logic on scucess
        },
        error: function (error) { //same logic as success.
            hideLoader(timeBeforeAjax);
            //logic on error
        }
    })
```